# Will MacBook still show as Offline in find my iPhone after it's been restored?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, find-my-iphone, find-my-mac

I have received so many different answers and I'm hoping to get one from someone who knows about this specific issue.

My MacBook Pro was stolen last week, but it is still showing on my devices on find my iPhone as "offline." If the thief wiped the laptop, would it still show as offline or would it be completely removed? I read something about it being possibly stored in the NVRAM so it could still show up like it is but I want to be certain. 
Thank you so much for your answers

Comment: If you sign into iCloud on the wiped Mac, your iPhone will see it as Online. Find my iPhone is tied to Apple accounts rather than specific devices.

Comment: @jack thank you for your response, however I'm wondering if whoever stole my laptop wiped it, would it still show up as offline on find my iPhone because that's what it shows. I'm trying to see if they restored my laptop or not. Thanks!